# Check if an integer is divisible by another integer (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, integer, division

I need to check if an integer is divisible by another integer exactly.

If not I would like to round it up to the closest multiple of the number.

Example:

```
var numberOne = 3
var numberTwo = 5
```

`numberTwo` is not a multiple of `numberOne` therefore I would like it to round `numberTwo` up to 6.

How would I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 29):

**1) If you want to check or an integer is divided by another integer:**

### Swift 5

```
if numberOne.isMultiple(of: numberTwo) { ... }
```

### Swift 4 or less

```
if numberOne % numberTwo == 0 { ... }
```

**2) Function to round to the closest multiple value:**

```
func roundToClosestMultipleNumber(_ numberOne: Int, _ numberTwo: Int) -> Int {
    var result: Int = numberOne
    
    if numberOne % numberTwo != 0 {
        if numberOne < numberTwo {
            result = numberTwo
        } else {
            result = (numberOne / numberTwo + 1) * numberTwo
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use the modulo operator `%`:

```
numberTwo % numberOne == 0
```

The modulo finds the remainder of an integer division between 2 numbers, so for example:

```
20 / 3 = 6
20 % 3 = 20 - 6 * 3 = 2
```

The result of 20/3 is 6.666667 - the dividend (20) minus the integer part of that division multiplied by the divisor (3 * 6) is the modulo (20 - 6 * 3) , equal to 2 in this case.

If the modulo is zero, then the dividend is a multiple of the divisor

More info about the modulo at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) wikipedia page.

Comment: The first part is working for me however I am not sure what the bottom line means. How do I work out what I should add to the 20 to make it divisible by 3? I would like to round it up. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer - hope that explains a little bit.

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 5

> **isMultiple(of:)**
>
> Returns true if this value is a multiple of the given
> value, and false otherwise.
>
> `func isMultiple(of other: Int) -> Bool`

```
let rowNumber = 4

if rowNumber.isMultiple(of: 2) {
    print("Even")
} else {
    print("Odd")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `truncatingRemainder`. E.g.,

```
if number.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 10) == 0 {                
    print("number is divisible by 10")   
}
```